# Trying to do a cosine rule formula in python however not giving the expected output

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

If I select missing angle function and put for example a = 10, b = 10, c = 10, the expected output is 60 degrees for the angle, however the output from the program is 0.1546...

```
import math, sys

def missingAngle():
    sideA = int(input("size of side a = "))
    sideB = int(input("size of side b = "))
    sideC = int(input("size of side c = "))

    answer = math.acos((sideB**2 + sideC**2 - sideA**2) / (2 * sideB * sideC))

    return answer

def missingSide():
    angleA = int(input("size of angle A = "))
    sideB = int(input("size of side b = "))
    sideC = int(input("size of side c = "))

    answer = math.sqrt(sideB**2 + sideC**2 - 2 * sideB * sideC * math.cos(angleA))

    return answer

missingSideOrAngle = input("Are you trying to work out the missing angle or side?(Angle/Side) = ")

while True:
    if missingSideOrAngle.title() == "Angle":
        print("Your answer is = " + str(missingAngle()))
        sys.exit()

    elif missingSideOrAngle.title() == "Side":
        print("Your answer is = " + str(missingSide()))
        sys.exit()

    else:
        missingSideOrAngle = input("Please enter a valid string(Angle/Side) = ")
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.
The most common cause is that you neglected to convert your angles between degrees and radians.

Comment: The code as supplied does run.  When I ran Daniel's 10, 10, 10, scenario, it returned ```1.0471975511965979``` , which is expected.  As noted by Prune, ```math.acos``` returns radians, not degrees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never could reproduce the error that yielded the erroneous 0.1546.

Here is your program with a few tweaks that will help you towards expanding the programs' abilities:

```
import math

def missingAngle():
    sideA = float(input("size of side a = "))
    sideB = float(input("size of side b = "))
    sideC = float(input("size of side c = "))
    try:
        answer = math.acos((sideB**2 + sideC**2 - sideA**2) / (2 * sideB * sideC))
        return f'Your answer is: {math.degrees(answer):.2f} degrees'
    except ValueError:
        return 'Values given cannot form a triangle'

def missingSide():
    angleA = math.radians(float(input("size of angle A (degrees) = ")))
    sideB = float(input("size of side b = "))
    sideC = float(input("size of side c = "))

    answer = math.sqrt(sideB**2 + sideC**2 - 2 * sideB * sideC * math.cos(angleA))
    return f'Your answer is: {answer:.2f} units'


while True:
    missingSideOrAngle = input("Are you trying to work out the missing angle or side?(Angle/Side) = ")
    if missingSideOrAngle.title() == "Angle":
        print(missingAngle())

    elif missingSideOrAngle.title() == "Side":
        print(missingSide())

    else:
        missingSideOrAngle = input("Please enter a valid string(Angle/Side) = ")
```

I made it an actual loop, so it will let the user run scenarios endlessly until they hit `Ctrl-C` or enter something that raises an unhandled error.  I have not tried to account for all possible errors.

The `missingAngle` is made to return degrees.  It also includes a ``'try-except``` block to catch the error that will occur if the three sides cannot form a real triangle (eg: 12, 45, 85).  The inputs are cast to floats, so the user may enter decimals of distance or angles, and the returns are formatted to render to 2 decimal places.

This should help you on your way.  You may want to design error handling for user inputs to the number fields that are not numbers, and run some tests on the `missingSide` to see what can go wrong with user inputs and catch these.  One you might want to experiment with is giving it an angle of 180.  Some values may not yield an actual error, but may yield unexpected results.

Good Luck!